# Is there a word that describes a person who dies on his/her birthdate?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

I have found references to birthdays and "deathdays," many words that reference either death or birth (natalis, obitus, quietus) but not both sharing the same day and month (even sharing the same year in the case of some children).

Comment: Your examples (natalis, obitus, quietus) are not English words though English words may have evolved from them.  Is there a word that fits your request in another language?  I don't know of such a word in English, myself. How would you use that word in a sentence?

Comment: Please note that the "single-word-requests" tag has a phrase in capitals: YOU MUST INCLUDE A SAMPLE SENTENCE DEMONSTRATING HOW THE WORD WOULD BE USED.

Comment: "Unlucky" comes to mind, though "obsessive" might also fit.

Comment: "birthday parting"

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, it is **"neonatal death"**. It is used to imply the death of newborn baby in first 28 days.

A person who died on his birthday is described as "**birthday-perisher**"

Comment: Do you have any evidence that "birthday-perisher" is used? I have not been able to find any instance of it on the internet.

Comment: Here is the link. http://newsfeed.time.com/2012/06/12/study-youre-most-likely-to-die-on-your-own-birthday/

Comment: Adding that information into your post would be good. (In this case, it looks like "birthday-perisher" is a nonce word Time created, but that at least gives it a little credibility.)

Answer (score 0):

There is one expression that might be suitable for this case and it's stillbirth.
Stillbirth is often defined as fetal death after 20 weeks of gestation,but a fetus greater than any combination of 16 to 28 weeks gestational age.