# someone who dies, not at birth, but years later, ON their birthday?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a specific word for someone who dies, not at birth, but years later, ON their birthday? An historical person who comes to mind would be inventor John Harrison, who was born 
March 24, 1693, and died on his birthday, 
March 24, 1774.

What would you call this event or person, other than deceased? Is there a special name for dying on one's birthday?

The reason my question may be different is because the answers given to the 1st question seemed to not be answering the question asked because of a misunderstanding of the nature of the question.  People kept answering about babies miscarried or stillborn on their date of birth, not birthday. I am attempting to clarify the responses given by rephrasing the question into something clearer that will bring about the answer asked originally asked for.

Comment: This question, as you know, is a duplicate of [Is there a word that describes a person who dies on his/her birthdate?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/281410/191178), but the one upvoted answer there appears to give a neologism (and a phrase that doesn't fit here), so I guess it doesn't make sense to close it as a duplicate. (Ideally, you should mention why the answers don't work in your question.)

Comment: I understand that you are looking for a special word like "palindrome" for a word/phrase that reads the same backward as forward -  a word that immediately designated someone "who died at 90 on his birthday" ?  Is the place it will be used for a tab or category label that absolutely demands brevity ?

Comment: FWIW, I would strongly contend that, at least in popular american English, that "birthday" is an aniversary of their day of birth.  A person's 1st birthday is a year after you they are born.  "Birthday Deaths" might be a good header for a list of  names and I doubt people would expect infants that "died at birth" to be on the list.  "Summer Deaths" would convey a list of people who died during the summer for example.

Comment: How many adults do you know died on their birthday? One? More than one? Several?  Or none? Adults who happen to die on the same day they were born, is rare. Very rare. There is no "word" for such a rare event if it ever becomes frequent, or a feature of euthanasia (who knows, stranger things have happened)  then someone, somewhere will come up with an expression.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - It's not that uncommon. It should happen, on average, in about 1 in 365 cases... Statistics actually show it to be the most likely day to die on, though as I recall from the book Freakonomics this may be a case of poor records rather than high statistical likelihood.

Comment: Actually what got me thinking about it is that, statistically, after age 60, adults are slightly (only slightly) MORE likely to pass away on their birthday, than on another day, due to stress related conditions.

Comment: As far as it being a repeated question, the answers themselves seemed to be not answering the question asked because of a misunderstanding, so I'm rephrasing the question for clarity. People kept answering about babies miscarried or stillborn on their date of birth, not birthday.

Answer (score 0):

*Birthday effect* comes close. It relates to a slightly more generalised phenomenon rather than to the person.

> The birthday effect (sometimes called the birthday blues, especially when referring specifically to suicide) is a statistical phenomenon where an individual's likelihood of death appears to increase on or close to their birthday.
>   [- wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_effect)